# Combining List of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

dfs_list is a huge list of dataframes. For example here are three of the dataframes in the list:

```
[2501 rows x 2 columns],       ABCD TEST  ABCD TRIAL
Time                                           
0.000             NaN                  1.048793
0.002             NaN                  1.048793
0.004             NaN                  1.017976
0.006             NaN                  1.059065
0.008             NaN                  1.038521
...               ...                       ...
4.992             NaN                  0.997432
4.994             NaN                  1.007704
4.996             NaN                  1.007704
4.998             NaN                  0.987160
5.000             NaN                  0.001027

[2501 rows x 2 columns],        ABC TEST  ABC TRIAL
Time                                            
0.000          0.73632                  1.039654
0.002          0.76128                  1.021422
0.004          0.82368                  0.984959
0.006          0.74880                  1.021422
0.008          0.71136                  1.048769
...                ...                       ...
4.992          0.72384                  1.012306
4.994          0.71136                  1.030538
4.996          0.76128                  0.984959
4.998          0.69888                  1.021422
5.000          0.03744                 -0.008660

[2501 rows x 2 columns]]
[      ABDCE TEST  ABCDE TRIAL
Time                                           
0.000             NaN                  1.065354
0.002             NaN                  1.065354
0.004             NaN                  1.048597
0.006             NaN                  1.048597
0.008             NaN                  1.065354
...               ...                       ...
4.992             NaN                  0.989946
4.994             NaN                  1.006703
4.996             NaN                  1.006703
4.998             NaN                  1.006703
5.000             NaN                  0.001257
```

I want to combine the list of dataframes to have an output like this:

```
                ABCD TEST     ABCD TRIAL    ABC TEST    ABC TRIAL   ABDCE TEST   ABCDE TRIAL

    Time                                           
    0.000       NaN        1.048793        0.73632        1.039654         NaN      1.065354
    0.002       NaN        1.048793        0.76128        1.021422         NaN      1.065354
    0.004       NaN        1.017976        0.82368        0.984959         NaN      1.048597
    0.006       NaN        1.059065        0.74880        1.021422         NaN      1.048597
    0.008       NaN        1.038521        0.71136        1.048769         NaN      1.065354
    ...         ...             ...            ...             ...         ...           ...
    4.992       NaN        0.997432        0.72384        1.012306         NaN      0.989946
    4.994       NaN        1.007704        0.71136        1.030538         NaN      1.006703
    4.996       NaN        1.007704        0.76128        0.984959         NaN      1.006703
    4.998       NaN        0.987160        0.69888        1.021422         NaN      1.006703
    5.000       NaN        0.001027        0.03744       -0.008660         NaN      0.001257
```

All of the dataframes are 2501 rows x 2 columns and have 'Time' as the index. All the 'Time' index values are exactly the same for all the dataframes.

When I do:

```
pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=1)
```

The output is a dataframe that has a lot of Nan values.

The closest I have gotten is using this code:

```
reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs_list)
```

This correctly combines all the dataframes in dfs_list but only outputs the first row (Time = 0.0).

To address the comment if I used ignore_index the dataframe result is:

```
       0         1    2         3        4    ...       383      384       385  386       387
Time                                          ...                                            
0.000  NaN  1.065354  NaN  1.048793  0.73632  ...  1.010290  0.64896  0.803985  NaN  0.665822
0.002  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
0.002  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
0.002  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
0.002  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
...    ...       ...  ...       ...      ...  ...       ...      ...       ...  ...       ...
4.998  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN  0.66144  0.934120  NaN       NaN
4.998  NaN  1.006703  NaN  0.987160  0.69888  ...  0.991581      NaN       NaN  NaN  1.037600
4.998  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
5.000  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
5.000  NaN  0.001257  NaN  0.001027  0.03744  ... -0.009355  0.00000  0.006913  NaN  0.234896
```

EDIT:
What if I remove the time column all together and reset the index? I don't really care about the time column.. just the TEST AND TRIAL columns. Then the df_list would look like this:

```
[2501 rows x 2 columns],      ABCD TEST  ABCD TRIAL
4893             NaN                  1.048793
4894             NaN                  1.048793
4895             NaN                  1.017976
4896             NaN                  1.059065
4897             NaN                  1.038521
...              ...                       ...
7389             NaN                  0.997432
7390             NaN                  1.007704
7391             NaN                  1.007704
7392             NaN                  0.987160
7393             NaN                  0.001027

[2501 rows x 2 columns],       ABC TEST  ABC TRIAL
4007          0.73632                  1.039654
4008          0.76128                  1.021422
4009          0.82368                  0.984959
4010          0.74880                  1.021422
4011          0.71136                  1.048769
...               ...                       ...
6503          0.72384                  1.012306
6504          0.71136                  1.030538
6505          0.76128                  0.984959
6506          0.69888                  1.021422
6507          0.03744                 -0.008660

[2501 rows x 2 columns]]
[     ABCDE TEST  ABCDE TRIAL
4862             NaN                  1.065354
4863             NaN                  1.065354
4864             NaN                  1.048597
4865             NaN                  1.048597
4866             NaN                  1.065354
...              ...                       ...
7358             NaN                  0.989946
7359             NaN                  1.006703
7360             NaN                  1.006703
7361             NaN                  1.006703
7362             NaN                  0.001257
```

However, if I try `pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` the output is still:

```
      0    1    2    3    4    ...  383  384  385  386       387
12    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
13    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
14    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
15    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
16    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...       ...
7491  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.970004
7492  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.978454
7493  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.020701
7494  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.037600
7495  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.234896
```

Comment: `pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=1, ignore_index = True)`?

Comment: From your post, looks like `dfs_list` contains differently indexes dataframes?

Answer (score 3):

Let's use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join).

```
df_list[0].join(df_list[1:])
```

Notes on join

> Join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key column.
>   Efficiently join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once by
>   passing a list.
>
> other : DataFrame, Series, or ***list of DataFrame***